# verificação e adição em CSV e PHP

Tags: php, csv

Preciso que meu script cada vez que submetido escreva uma nova linha em meu arquivo .csv assim como está e não substitua a linha que já existe, e também que faça uma verificação se já existe um $email já cadastrado e se houver que pare a execução e não escreva nada.
Ficarei muito grato se me ajudarem !!

```
$arquivo = fopen('duvidas.csv','w');
    while(true) {
    $linha = fgets($arquivo);
    if ($linha==null) break;
}
$texto = "$nome,$email,$nasc";
fwrite ($arquivo, $texto);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use o `fgetcsv` do PHP: veja https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgetcsv.php

> Similar à função fgets(), exceto que a fgetcsv() interpreta a linha em busca de campos no formato CSV e retorna um array contendo os campos lidos.

```
$arquivo = fopen('duvidas.csv','w');

$email_cadastrado = false;

while ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle) ) !== FALSE ) {
   if($data[1] == $email){//$data[1] é a posicao do email no seu array!?
      $email_cadastrado = true; break;
   }
}
//se o email nao estive cadastrado, insere
if(!$email_cadastrado){
   $texto = "$nome,$email,$nasc";
   fwrite ($arquivo, $texto);
}
```